# Extract object elements from arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which outputs like:

```
[]
0: {emailAddress: "xxx", squats: "0", steps: "4500", WorkoutDate: "12-5-2020", pullUps: "0", …}
1: {emailAddress: "yyy", squats: "4000", steps: "0", WorkoutDate: "10-5-2020", pullUps: "0", …}
2: {emailAddress: "zzz", WorkoutDate: "05-08-2020"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

What is the best way to iterate through these items and extract values?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Best" is a tricky thing to describe and it depends on the point of view and requirements. You should try to clarify if you want a short, fast, declarative ... etc. solution. In CS the best answer is "it depends". So :) define your dependencies. You can loop like:
```
[{..}, {...}, {...}].forEach(x => {
    // do stuff with the array of values...
    Object.values(x)

    // do stuff with the array of keys
    Object.keys(x)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple solutions possible for this scenario. I prefer you to use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), or [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to loop through the array and [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) method to loop through the object properties. `array.map` creates a new array whereas `array.forEach` do not create a new array instance.

Sample solution

```js
const arr = [
  {emailAddress: "xxx", squats: "0", steps: "4500", WorkoutDate: "12-5-2020", pullUps: "0"},
  {emailAddress: "yyy", squats: "4000", steps: "0", WorkoutDate: "10-5-2020", pullUps: "0"},
  {emailAddress: "zzz", WorkoutDate: "05-08-2020"}
];
arr.forEach((item) => {
  for (const property in item) {
    console.log(`${property}: ${item[property]}`);
  }
})
```

Comment: I'd advice to use `forEach` instead of `map` if you do not want to create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to iterate through the contents of an array:

```js
const objects = [
  { "name" : "John" },
  { "name" : "Tess" },
  { "name" : "Tomi" }
];

// Foreach
objects.forEach(currentObject => console.log(currentObject.name));

// For of
for (const currentObject of objects ) {
  console.log(currentObject.name);
} 
 
// For-loop
for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  console.log(objects[i].name);
}
```

Comment: This works only if object has a property name. OP's object has a bunch of properties out of which none is name.

Comment: @kopz This is an example of different ways to iterate over objects in an array, shouldn't be too hard for OP to take the example and adapt it for the shape of his objects.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{
    emailAddress: "xxx",
    squats: "0",
    steps: "4500",
    WorkoutDate: "12-5-2020",
    pullUps: "0"
  },
  {
    emailAddress: "yyy",
    squats: "4000",
    steps: "0",
    WorkoutDate: "10-5-2020",
    pullUps: "0"
  },
  {
    emailAddress: "zzz",
    WorkoutDate: "05-08-2020"
  }
];

arr.forEach((arr, i, val) => {
  val[i] = Object.values(val[i]);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this way too:

```js
var arr = [{ emailAddress: "xxx", squats: "0", steps: "4500", WorkoutDate: "12-5-2020", pullUps: "0"  },{ emailAddress: "yyy", squats: "4000", steps: "0",    WorkoutDate: "10-5-2020", pullUps: "0"  }, { emailAddress: "zzz", WorkoutDate: "05-08-2020"}];

arr.forEach((val)=>{
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(val)) {
     console.log(`Value of ${key} is ${value}!`);
  }
});
```